# In Vue, can I transfer props?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Imagine I have a `<progress-bar>` UI component and I want to create an `<app-progress-bar>` component that is the same as the `<progress-bar>` but with some style tweaks.

AppProgressBar.vue:

`<template>
  <progress-bar class="app-progress-bar"></progress-bar>
</template>`

This will break because `<progress-bar>` requires a `percent` prop. So I can pass it in:

`<progress-bar class="app-progress-bar" percent="percent"></progress-bar>`

This seems fine, but is brittle when `<progress-bar>` has many props. Can I simply pass through all props? Theoretical syntax:

`<progress-bar class="app-progress-bar" {...props}></progress-bar>`

Which is similar to React/JSX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching this, I don't think it's possible. Instead, you can `extend` a component and put an `extraClass` key on `data` or `computed`:

```
import ProgressBar from './ProgressBar'

export default {
  extends: ProgressBar,
  data() {
    return { extraClass: 'app-progress-bar' }
  }
}
```

ProgressBar.vue:

```
<template>
  <div class="progress-bar" :class="extraClass">...</div>
</template>
```

This isn't as clean or flexible as React, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

Like already answered, extending the component would be a nice way to create your components in this scenario. Similar to class inheritance in other languages.

However, you can also pass an object as prop. If you want to keep things clean, and don't want to extend your components, you could pass a prop like this:

```
//object with many values that you need to pass. for ex.
myObjectWithSuff: { percent: 10%, someOtherStuff: value, ... } 

<progress-bar class="app-progress-bar" myProp="myObjectWithStuff"></progress-bar>
```

Inside the `progress-bar` component, declare the prop `myProp`. Then you can access any properties on that object. For example: `this.myProp.percent`.

This is just quick and simple, but depending on your architecture, extending components may be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

**Abstract**

This can be done by binding $attrs to the child. So in your case it would be:

```
<template>
  <progress-bar v-bind="$attrs" class="app-progress-bar"></progress-bar>
</template>
```

**Link to Docs**

> vm.$attrs: Contains parent-scope attribute bindings (except for class and style)...and can be passed down to an inner component

Source: [Vue $attrs documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-attrs)

**Example**

Let's say that a component called `<inner>` has a boolean prop called `dark` and a string prop called `color`.

Now let's define an outer component called `<outer>` which wraps `<inner>` in its definition.

```
<template>
  <inner></inner>
</template>
.
.
.
name: 'outer'
```

The issue here is if we use the `<outer>` component, we can't transfer the dark and color props through to the `<inner>` component which knows what to do with them. For example `<inner dark color="blue"></inner>` works, but `<outer dark color="blue"></outer>` doesn't.

If you change the definition of `<outer>` to include the `$attrs` binding, it will transfer all the props for you (this doesn't include `style` and `class`). Here is the new definition:

```
<template>
  <inner v-bind="$attrs"></inner>
</template>
.
.
.
name: 'outer'
```

Now you can use `<outer dark color="blue"></outer>`.

**Additional note**

You can also use the `inheritAttrs` prop to prevent this behaviour by default. You can take a look at the [official Vue docs here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#inheritAttrs) and I also found [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/changjoo_park/pzx08wp9/) which gives an example of `inheritAttrs` being used.